# Kafka streams metadataForKey returns null for any key after running well for 3-4 days

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

1. As per my understanding, metadataForKey uses default partitioner to determine, which partition and host can hold a particular key. So, in that case if the kafka topic has the data and the local state store has the data, what causes metadataForKey or default partitioner to fail only after 3-4 days.
2. Is there a way to manually trigger the rebuilding of this metadata information
3. Or considering that it works fine initially and only starts to fail after 3-4 days, is it a memory issue and if so, is there any cleanup process that I am missing

The following API call is returning null after few days:

```
metadata = kafkaStreams.metadataForKey(storename, key, Serdes.String().serializer());
if (metadata == null) {
    return null;
}
```

Streams Properites Configuration:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, APP_ID);
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, POD_IP + ":" + REST_ENDPOINT_PORT);
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.ByteArray().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 1);

props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
props.put(StreamsConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, 1000);
props.put(StreamsConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 2147483647);

// This configuration is used as the default timeout for all consumer operations
// that do not explicitly accept a timeout parameter e.g committing offsets, close etc
props.put(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);

props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 500);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);

props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, STREAMS_APP_ID);


// If data on a particular Topic is exactly 1Mb then, for streams we may add
// extra bytes because of the metadata that needs to be added from headers into payload).
// The broker is using default numbers for each topic which is 1Mb, hence the insertion fails
// The below settings will take care from the producer side as well as
// the internal topic, allowing messages upto 2mb.
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 2097152);
props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX + TopicConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "lz4");
props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX + TopicConfig.MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES_CONFIG, 2097152);
```

State Store Setup with Custom Processor:

```
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        // Storebuilder required to register and create a State Store
        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, byte[]>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
                Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(STREAMS_STATE_STORE),
                        Serdes.String(),
                        Serdes.ByteArray());

        // Parameter to control the Fault-Tolerant changelog topic creation for a state store
        Map<String, String> changelogConfig = new HashMap<>();
        changelogConfig.put("min.insync.replicas", "1");

        keyValueStoreBuilder.withLoggingEnabled(changelogConfig);

        /*
         * Topology builder required to set the topic and connect it with Customizable state stores and
         * Processors to modify the stream of data
         */
        final Topology topology = builder.build();

        String kafka_topic = KAFKA_PREFIX;

        /*
         * add the source processor node that takes Kafka topic as input
         */
        topology.addSource("input", kafka_topic);


        // Add a custom processor that reads from the source topic
        topology.addProcessor("the-processor",
                /*
                 * This is your custom processor that implements
                 * the `Processor` interface, see further down below.
                 */
                (ProcessorSupplier<String, byte []>) () -> new CustomProcessor(STREAMS_STATE_STORE),
                "input");

        // Connect your custom state store to the custom processor above
        topology.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder, "the-processor");

        // Get the stream config Properties to configure Stream Threads, Consumers etc used by Streams Library
        Properties props = getKafkaStreamsProperties();
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
```

Custom Processor:

```
public class CustomProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, byte []> {
   ...
   ...

   public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
       /*
        * Schedule a punctuate() method every 3 second based on stream-time
        */
        context.schedule(Duration.ofMillis(3000), PunctuationType.STREAM_TIME, (timestamp) -> {
            KeyValueIterator<String, byte[]> iter = this.kvStore.all();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                KeyValue<String, byte[]> entry = iter.next();
                context.forward(entry.key, entry.value);
            }
            iter.close();
            // commit the current processing progress
            context.commit();
        });

        /*
         * Punctuation to delete the records marked for deletion.
         * Then Mark nnew messages for deletion in the next cycle
         */
        context.schedule(Duration.ofSeconds(Integer.parseInt(Constants.KAFKA_STREAMS_CACHE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL)),
                PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, timestamp -> {
           /*
            * iterate over all records and remove them based on some criteria
            */
            this.kvStore.all().forEachRemaining(keyValue -> {
                 ...
                 ...
                 // delete keys based on certain condition
                 this.kvStore.delete(keyValue.key);
                 ...
                 ...
            }

           /* 
            * iterate over all records and mark the new messages for deletion
            */
            KeyValueIterator<String, byte[]> iter = this.kvStore.all();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                KeyValue<String, byte[]> entry = iter.next();
                ...
                kvStore.put(entry.key, updated_msg_byteArr);
                ...
                ...
            }
            iter.close()
   }

   public void process(String s1, byte[] s2) {
    JsonObject payload = new JsonObject();
    ...
    ...

    if (kvstore.get(s1) {
       // For duplicate key, we dont want to overwrite the original data, instead store it with key: "original_key1"
       s1 = s1 + "1";
    }

    // convert the payload to byte array
    kvStore.put(s1, streamsByteArr);
}
```

Format of data stored in state-stores is:

```
Key (String): MjFjZmQ3MjAtMGY2My0xMWViLWJjODItN2ZmY2RkMjExMDc1MTFkZGJjMGVjNTg4NDZjMDg0NmQ4YTBmYjhjOTRjZTE 
Payload: byteArray([.., .., ...])
Headers: str1:val1, str2:val2
```

When I dug deeper, the problem is actually with state store itself. I removed all the metadata checks and reading the state store directly now using:

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, byte[]> store = kafkaStreams.store(storename,
                                           QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore())
byte[] value = store.get(key);
```

The above call is returning a null. Eventhough I see the log when I am pushing the data into statestore in the CustomProcessor, the above state store lookup is failing. Any suggestions why this could happen. Am I missing a property in my StreamsConfig setup or do I have incorrectly tuned parameters. Appreciate all the help in advance!

Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the "store retention time", and what are the "changelog topic retention settings (time, bytes)"? Please show the code how the store is setup.

Comment: @Beryllium Updated the original question with State Store setup and Custom Processor that I am using to use the ProcessotContext handle. I am managing the store retention time as 2 minutes (120 seconds) using Punctuators and store.delete() method. For changelog topic, I am using the default provided settings except for min.insync.replicas.

Comment: When I dug deeper, the problem is actually with state store itself. I removed all the metadata checks and reading the state store directly now using:  
    ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, byte[]> store = kafkaStreams.store(storename,
                                               QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore())
    byte[] value = store.get(key);
The above call is returning a null.

Comment: Eventhough I see the log when I am pushing the data into statestore in the CustomProcessor, the above state store lookup is failing. Any suggestions why this could happen. Am I missing a property in my StreamsConfig setup or do I have incorrectly tuned parameters. Appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: What does `allMetadata()` return? The metadata is recomputed each time a rebalance happens. How many instanced to you run? --- Btw: it seems you don't really use the `StreamsBuilder` (ie, only to get a `Topology`)... You can also just do `new Topology()` to create an empty topology without using the `StreamsBuilder`. -- Another thing: you will need to `close()` your iterators over the state stores to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: 1. I am running 2 instances of this app (Its a kubernetes deployment, so scalable to 4 instance dynamically).    
2. allMetadata returns the correct number of host:port instances (2).    
3. Sure, I will remove the StreamsBuilder.   
4. I have created a debug endpoint to give all the StateStore keys. When I run into this issue, the StateStore doesnt have my key, eventhough I can see a log where it is successfully pushed using (kvStore.put())...is there a commit or something that is missing after the put ? But why would it only fail intermittently.

Comment: After you `store.put()` is executed, the data should be available for querying. There is no extra step for you to do. -- What do you get if you call `store.all()` instead of `get(key)`? -- I also want to point out again, that you need to close all iterators! (Maybe your code snipped is incomplete, but only the first part shows a `iter.close()` call -- btw: I would recommend to use a try-with-resources clause to ensure that iterators are closed even in case of failure.

Comment: 1. Thats what I did in the debug endpoint I mentioned ->store.all() . store.all() doesn't have the key I am looking for. And in my app the key lookup is happening in a polling fashion, meaning another app is polling using a REST endpoint to read the data, so the lookup is happening within seconds of pushing the data into state store.(polling goes on for 60 seconds, so that should be enough time)
2. I am doing iter.close()..updated my code above. Sure I will convert everything to try-with-resources.

Comment: One more thing to highlight is:
1. `kvStore.put` is successfull (using processor context `(KeyValueStore<String, byte[]>) context.getStateStore(stateStoreName))`

2. store.get(key) and store.all() missing the key (using ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, byte[]> store)

3. in my cleanup process using `context Processor Pucntuators (after 2 minutes)` -> `kvStore.delete(key)`, the key is found and deleted

So the `context processor` lookup succeeds but the `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore` fails ?

Comment: Does the issue go away if you run with a single instance instead of two?

Comment: I haven't ran it continuously with 1 instance but didn't encounter a failure with 1 instance yet. I will try and run for longer period with 1 instance. Any thoughts in that direction, what could be the issue, if the failure only happens with multiple instances and not with 1 instance ?

Comment: My gut feeling would be, that the key you try to query is on the other instance. -- Not sure how you track the logs, as you say you can see in the log that the message is processed (and deleted). Can you verify that the logs belong to the right instance? -- Remember: a `get` is always for the local instance only -- it does not do a remote call (you would need to implement your own routing layer for remote calls if a key "lives" on a different instance). -- And an `all()` would only iterate over the local shard of the state store. If there is one instance, there is no remote case though.

Comment: It's still unclear to me throw, why `metadataForKey()` does return `null` though. -- But this could also be a bug. (What version of Kafka Streams are you using?)

Comment: Even if there was a bug in reading the key from incorrect instance, when I run the `store.all()` it doesnt show the keys, and I am making sure to manually run the store.all() in both the instances. And clearly see the keys missing in both the instances. Besides, as you mentioned I started with metadataForKey failing, which I removed it eventually. I am running kafka version 2.4.1

Comment: Updated the maven libraries info in my post above

Comment: It's unclear to me what the issue could be -- if you can reproduce the issue reliable, maybe best to open a bug report with all details to reproduce it (best as a unit test if possible).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I updated the following streams properties and havent seen the issue for atleast a week (I hope I am not jinxing it!).  
                `props.put(StreamsConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 100);
  props.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG), "1");
  props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 500);
  props.put(StreamsConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 600000);`

Does any of that ring a bell ?
I think the issue was with commit interval, not sure though

Comment: Not sure. `retries` might affect rebalancing in KS (btw: the producer default for `retries` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so you might want to set it back to this -- atm, you reduce it to 100 as a "side effect"). -- Producer ack is 1 by default so it should not change anything. -- Hard to say for the other 3...

Comment: We have hit this issue again. It ran fine for 2 weeks, but the app was restarted last night and since then we see this issue getting hit intermittently again